# How can I test that a Camel route calls different endpoints in order?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I use Apache Camel to orchestrate a number of HTTP calls to three different endpoints. This works correctly, but I'd like to unit test this Camel route as well.

I can correctly assert that the three endpoints were called, but I don't know how to verify that they were called in the correct order. I have looked into using `MockEndpoint` and `NotifyBuilder`.

How can I verify in a Camel Spring JUnit test that the endpoints were called in the correct order?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I am not certain if there is an easy way to do this, but you could use the AdviceWithRouteBuilder to weave a bean into your route that puts a counter in the header before each send.

Something like:

```
weaveById("send1")
    .before()
    .bean(CounterIncrementor.class);

weaveById("send2")
    .before()
    .bean(CounterIncrementor.class);

weaveById("send3")
    .before()
    .bean(CounterIncrementor.class);
```

..................

```
List<Exchange> list = getMockEndpoint("mock:extract").getReceivedExchanges();
Exchange exchange = list.get(1);
Message in = exchange.getIn();
in.getHeader("MyCounterHeader", Integer.class);

//TODO verify you received the correct number
```